Mysterious Towers
This mysterious polygon looks like a bit like a city skyline.

It's not, but it is closely associated with a particular city. Can anyone tell me which one?

Looks like a timeline where the peaks represent an increase in something, hmmm

V frr frira "yriryf/sybbef" fb V gubhtug znlor ercerfragf frira qvfp Unabv Gbjre jvgu gur cbyltba ercerfragvat zvavzhz zbirf (fgrc-ol-fgrc) ohg unira'g orra noyr gb znxr frafr bs vg. Is this off? (So that I can leave this idea if it is, been stuck with me for a while)

@Prim3numbah lbh ner evtug nobhg gur yriryf (npghnyyl gurer ner 8 vs lbh gnxr gur "tebhaq" gb or yriry 0) ohg gurl ner eryngrq gb trareny xabjyrqtr, abg zngurzngvpf.

@uggupuggu lbh ner evtug gung vg'f n gvzryvar, and if you want another hint, gur k-nkvf fgnegf ng bar gubhfnaq. I'll add further hints to the OP in due course.

This represents

The city of London!!

Because

This is a timeline of English monarchs from 1000 AD, and the heights of the bars are their regnal numbers!!



Hence, the city is the location of Buckingham Palace - London!


Great puzzle!! Very enjoyable, had a moment of inspiration when reading the hint about x starting at 1000 and probably also helps I'm British :P

Well done! I'm happy that someone got it!
